# Python in Visual Studio - Math doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I have some problems with the function Math and sqrt in Visual studio, does anyone can say me what i'm doing wrong?

```
print("Programa de calculo de raiz cuadrada")

numero= int(input("Introduce un numero: "))

intentos=0 

while numero<0:

    print("no se puede calcular la raiz de un numero negativo")

    if intentos==2:
        print("Has consumido demasiados intentos, reinicia aplicacion")
        break

    numero= int(input("Introduce un numero: "))
    if numero<0:
        intentos=intentos+1

if intentos<3:
    solución= math.sqrt(numero) # Here's the problem

    print("La raíz cuadrada de" +str(numero) + "es" +str(solución))
```

## Python #VisualStudio

Comment: You point out `math.sqrt(numero)` is the problem, but do not say what the problem is? Does python give you an error, or just the wrong answer?

Comment: What is the issue? Are you importing the math module with `import math`?

Comment: post the full code.

Comment: Hi @CoryKramer, python gives me back that:

File "c:/Users/aaron/Desktop/Curso/testing.py", line 20, in <module>
    solucion= math.sqrt(numero)
NameError: name 'math' is not defined

I want the Square Root, so how i have to do? Do i have to define the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `import math` to be able to use the `math` function.

It also has an error in the variable named `solución`, must be `solucion`.

Try this:

```
import math

print("Programa de calculo de raiz cuadrada")

numero= int(input("Introduce un numero: "))

intentos=0 

while numero<0:

    print("no se puede calcular la raiz de un numero negativo")

    if intentos==2:
        print("Has consumido demasiados intentos, reinicia aplicacion")
        break

    numero= int(input("Introduce un numero: "))
    if numero<0:
        intentos=intentos+1

if intentos<3:
    solucion= math.sqrt(numero)
    print("La raíz cuadrada de " +str(numero) + "es" +str(solucion))
```